# how to initiate Loader Manager in a class not in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-loadermanager

I want to make a util class for fetching data from database and store the fetched data in an array and then use it.
So I want need to implement loader manager callbacks method but I can not initiate loader manger.

Comment: if any knows please help!

Comment: Why should the util class have a loader? Ideally, you should call the utility class from the loader that is instantiated in your activity